# Extra session data not stored during SessionWizardView

Tags: python, django, session

I've got a Django `SessionWizardView` in which I want to add extra data for the user to take advantage of during the steps. Essentially I want to build a list, and a dict which stores information about the steps once they are complete.

The first step in the wizard allows a user to add information about themselves and at the end allows the option to add another person's details. If this option is selected another, conditional, form is rendered & I'd like to provide them with the option to use the data entered previously.

So during the `process_step()` method I'm creating a list, and then a corresponding dictionary of data for each step in the process. Initially I had these as class attributes, but feel they would be better suited in a user's session so I've attempted to add them like so;

```
def process_step(self, form):
    form_data = self.get_form_step_data(form)
    current_step = self.storage.current_step or ''
    data_dict = self.request.session.get('data_dict', dict())
    data_list = self.request.session.get('data_list', list())

    if current_step in data_dict:
        # Always replace the existing data for a step.
        data_dict.pop(current_step)

    if not isinstance(form, TermsForm):
        entrant_data = dict()

        for k, v in form_data.iteritems():
            entrant_data[k] = v

        for k in entrant_data.iterkeys():
            new_key = re.sub('{}-'.format(current_step), u'', k)
            entrant_data[new_key] = entrant_data.pop(k)

        data_dict[current_step] = entrant_data
        done = False
        for i, data in enumerate(data_list):
            if data[0] == current_step:
                data_list[i] = (
                    current_step, u'{} {}'.format(
                        entrant_data['first_name'],
                        entrant_data['last_name']
                    )
                )
                done = True

        if not done:
            data_list.append(
                (
                    current_step, u'{} {}'.format(
                        entrant_data['first_name'],
                        entrant_data['last_name']
                    )
                )
            )

    self.request.session['data_dict'] = data_dict
    self.request.session['data_list'] = data_list
    self.request.session.modified = True

    return form_data
```

After this method is ran my new session keys aren't part of the session. From what I've been reading, this is a valid way of setting session data, but have I made a mistake somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Of the top of my head, your `process_step` function call misses the explicit `request` parm. It's mostly called like this:

```
process_step(self, request, form, step):
```

Comment: Not according to the docs... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/#django.contrib.formtools.wizard.views.SessionWizardView